# mysql forcing a record to the top

Tags: sql, mysql, database, join

I am getting a list of people attending a course from a courses2011 table, the query is working but the client has asked us to make the person doing the query (they are logged in to the website) appear on top of the list. People won't be on the course for the full time hence the dates in my query.

Here is my current query:

```
select firstname, lastname, startdate, enddate, contactid, courseid, venueid from courses2011 where courseid = '4' 
and ((enddate > '2011-05-01') AND (startdate < '2011-05-20'))"
```

Say contactid "12345" is logged in to the site - How to I make a query so they appear first in the list.

Comment: your html code whre you embed the results would be helpfull

Comment: if you really have a table called xxxx2011... you need to rethink your data model.

Answer (score 3):

With the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT [...]
ORDER BY CASE WHEN contactid = '12345' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
```

Of course, you can have additional `ORDER BY` fields in the `ORDER BY` clause. And of course, you can read `'12345'` from a session table or use a bind variable or whatever way you're using to identify the logged in contact.

Answer (score 2):

one option is to add order by with condition like :

```
ORDER BY IF(contactid = "12345",0,1)
```

Comment: I am very impressed, you guys are very clever. Oddly enough, the client wants the person at the top then ordered by the registration date. I now know exactly how to do this by adding a second criteria to the order by. Anyway thanks for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 1):

There has been a similar query on SO. See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598793/sql-query-that-sorts-all-results-alphabetically-except-one) solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY contactid = 12345 DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY FIELD(contactid,12345) DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

you could use a `UNION`, like this:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, startdate, enddate, contactid, courseid, venueid
FROM courses2011
WHERE contactid = 12345

UNION

SELECT firstname, lastname, startdate, enddate, contactid, courseid, venueid
FROM courses2011
WHERE contactid <> 12345
  AND courseid = '4'
  AND ((enddate > '2011-05-01') AND (startdate < '2011-05-20'))
;
```

Comment: That's not guaranteed to work, because the `UNION` operator is not required to keep the ordering of tuples. You'll have to order the whole union

Comment: Union is also slow since it will force a "distinct" and you'll do two passes over courses2011.